# How can I remove the background white of flutter webview

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-inappwebview

I have used [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package to display a webview in a container. In my webview there is an image and some actions buttons at the bottom. After loading webview,  there is white space at bottom. How can I remove the white space of webview after loading ? I have set transparentbackground as true, but no change. Can I change the background of webview content as tranparent.

```
class _Itemdetails2State extends State<Itemdetails2> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();
  var scaffoldkey=GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
bool loaded=false,transparentbackground=false;
  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
  double height=10;
late PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController;
  late ContextMenu contextMenu;
  String url = "";
  String initialurl="";
  double progress = -1;
  final urlController = TextEditingController();
String html='';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    contextMenu = ContextMenu(
        menuItems: [
          ContextMenuItem(
              androidId: 1,
              iosId: "1",
              title: "Special",
              action: () async {
                print("Menu item Special clicked!");
                print(await webViewController?.getSelectedText());
                await webViewController?.clearFocus();
              })
        ],
        options: ContextMenuOptions(hideDefaultSystemContextMenuItems: false),
        onCreateContextMenu: (hitTestResult) async {
          print("onCreateContextMenu");
          print(hitTestResult.extra);
          print(await webViewController?.getSelectedText());
        },
        onHideContextMenu: () {
          print("onHideContextMenu");
        },
        onContextMenuActionItemClicked: (contextMenuItemClicked) async {
          var id = (Platform.isAndroid)
              ? contextMenuItemClicked.androidId
              : contextMenuItemClicked.iosId;
          print("onContextMenuActionItemClicked: " +
              id.toString() +
              " " +
              contextMenuItemClicked.title);
        });

    pullToRefreshController = PullToRefreshController(
      options: PullToRefreshOptions(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          webViewController?.reload();
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          webViewController?.loadUrl(
              urlRequest: URLRequest(url: await webViewController?.getUrl()));
        }
      },
    );
   
   
  }

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        key: scaffoldkey,
       
        body:WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async {
              return true;
            },child: Stack(
                children:<Widget>[ 

                  SafeArea(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      child: Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top-kToolbarHeight-MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom-MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                        child: Column(children:<Widget>[

                          Center(child:Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0,bottom: 15.0),
                              child: GestureDetector(onTap:(){
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                               //  print(progress);
                              },child:Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: const Color(0xffbc9b71), borderRadius:BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),

                                  child:FittedBox(fit:BoxFit.scaleDown,child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:20.0,vertical: 8.0),
                                      child:Text('CLOSE',style: TextStyle(letterSpacing:0.1,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,color:Colors.white,fontSize: 14,)))))))),
              Flexible(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0,right:20.0,bottom: 22.0),

                              child: Container(

                                child: Column(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    Flexible(
                                      child: InAppWebView(

                                        key: webViewKey,

                                      
                                        initialUrlRequest:
                                        URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(initialurl)),

                                        
                                        initialUserScripts: UnmodifiableListView<UserScript>([]),
                                        initialOptions:InAppWebViewGroupOptions(

                                            crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                                             supportZoom: true,
                                              javaScriptEnabled: true,
                                              transparentBackground:true,
                                              useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,disableVerticalScroll: true,
                                              preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.RECOMMENDED,
                                              mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
                                            ),
                                            android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
                                              useHybridComposition: true,
                                            ),
                                            ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
                                              allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
                                            )),
                                       // pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
                                        onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {

                                          

                                          webViewController = controller;
                                          controller.addJavaScriptHandler(

                                              handlerName: "newHeight",
                                              callback: (List<dynamic> arguments) async {
                                                int? height = arguments.isNotEmpty ? arguments[0] : await controller.getContentHeight();
                                                 setState(() => this.height = height!.toDouble());
                                              });
                                          //int? height=await controller.getContentHeight();
                                          
                                          setState(() {
                                            this.height=height;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                                          
                                          setState(()  {

                                         
                                            this.loaded=true;
                                            
                                            this.url = url.toString();
                                            urlController.text = this.url;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        androidOnPermissionRequest: (controller, origin, resources) async {
                                          return PermissionRequestResponse(
                                              resources: resources,
                                              action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                                        },
                                        shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
                                           var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                                          if (![
                                            "http",
                                            "https",
                                            "file",
                                            "chrome",
                                            "data",
                                            "javascript",
                                            "about"
                                          ].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                                            if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                                              // Launch the App
                                              await launch(
                                                url,
                                              );
                                              // and cancel the request
                                              return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                                            }
                                          }

                                          return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                                        },
                                        
                                      ),
                                      
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                   
]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )])));}}
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: Share your code for others to understand where the issue is

Comment: Now I attach the code.

Answer (score 0):

transparentBackground
bool? transparentBackground

Set to true to make the background of the WebView transparent. If your app has a dark theme, this can prevent a white flash on initialization. The default value is false.